# xpath works in console but doesn't work in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm learning web scraping and I'm trying to scrape this website http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_Data_MLB_HeightsWeights

so when I do "scrapy crawl baseket " the results is empty even when the `xpath` expersion is right

so it just gives me the Name , Team , Position , Height(inches) , Weight(pounds) but not the data

Please, if there's an answer, please explain the problem and how you know, if there's a way, cause I don't want to fail with the same problem again and thanks. .

I saw a problem like that and there someone said that table didn't contain a body I had tried to delete, but the same.

It doesn't work in the shell either.
here's the code:

```
import scrapy


class BasketSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basket"
    allowed_domains = ["wiki.stat.ucla.edu"]
     start_urls = ["http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_Data_MLB_HeightsWeights"]
 
def parse(self, response):
    for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="wikitablet"/body/tr]'):
        yield {
            'name': row.xpath('.//th[1]/text()').get(),
            'team': row.xpath('.//tr/th[2]/text()').get(),
            'position': row.xpath('.//tr/th[3]/text()').get(),
            'height': row.xpath('.//tr/th[4]/text()').get(),
            'weight': row.xpath('.//tr/th[5]/text()').get(),
             }
```

Comment: `body` might be added by the browser that's why `//table[@class="wikitablet"/body/tr` works on console. Try `//table[@class="wikitablet"]/tr`. Besides, your xpath expression is invalid since it's missing a closing square bracket.

Comment: stackoverflow made me edit my post that's why square brakets is missing 

about the tbody I tried to do it but it's the same , when is save the results to csv file the only thing appears is the first raw, the headers name , team ,etc ,but the data in the table doesn't

Comment: This is a working xpath `//table[@class="wikitable"]//tr` or `//table[@class="wikitable"]/tr`

Answer (score 0):

you have chooose wrong class in XPath

it's //table[@class="wikitable"]

you have used : [@class="wikitablet"

Answer (score 0):

The `tbody` element in injected by the browser and does not exist in the actual response.  You are also using `th` when you should be using `td` in the xpath expressions for each field.

You simply need to remove that portion in your initial xpath expression:

For example:

```
import scrapy


class BasketSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basket"
    allowed_domains = ["wiki.stat.ucla.edu"]
     start_urls = ["http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_Data_MLB_HeightsWeights"]
 
    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="wikitable"]/tr]'):
            yield {
                'name': row.xpath('.//td[1]/text()').get(),
                'team': row.xpath('.//td[2]/text()').get(),
                'position': row.xpath('.//td[3]/text()').get(),
                'height': row.xpath('.//td[4]/text()').get(),
                'weight': row.xpath('.//td[5]/text()').get(),
             }
```